# Application of the Riemann-Roch theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If C is a quadric hyperelliptic curve ($g(C)=3$ and the canonical line bundle is very ample)  contained in the two dimensional complex projective space and $K_C$ is the canonical line bundle of $\mathbb{P}^2$ restrected to my curve.
I take four distinct points on $C$ named $p_1,\ p_2,\ p_3,\ p_4 $ so $p_1+ p_2+p_3+p_4 \in K_C= |\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P^2}}(1)| $. Than i take another points different from the previous, named $q$ and the divisor on $C$ $\ D=p_1+ p_2+p_3+q$.
I want to compute
$h^o(D)$.
So using Riemann Roch theorem i can write:
$h^o(D)=h^1(D)+deg(D)-g+1=h^1(D)+4-3+1=h^1(D)+2$.
Now i've used Serre Duality and i get:
$h^1(D)=h^0(K_C-D)$. Is there a way to say that $h^0(K_C-D)=0$ for example using some vanishing theorem?

Comment: there is an error $K_C=(|\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P^2}}(1)|_C)$

Comment: sorry C is a QUARTIC curve NON hyperelliptic

Comment: $h^0(K_C-D)=h^0(p_4-q)$, and this is the dimension of the vector space of all rational functions $f$ on $C$ such that $\mbox{div}(f)+p_4-q\geq0$ (or $f=0$). This means that $f$ can only have one pole (at $p_4$) and must have a 0 at $q$ which can't be; therefore $f$ must be 0.

Comment: The function $z-q \fract{z-p_4} doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry in this case Why f would be a rational function?

Comment: i mean the function $\frac{z-q}{z-p_4}$. This function have $q$ as zero and $p_4$ as pole. So why doesn't it work?

Comment: Notice that that function is an isomorphism of $\mathbb{P}^1$ with itself, so it wouldn't work for any other curve (note that when writing $z$, you're specifying a local coordinate).

Comment: $f$ is a rational function because $H^0(C,\mathcal{O}_C(D))$ can be identified with the vector space of all rational functions $f$ that satisfy $\mbox{div}(f)+D\geq0$, along with 0. This is in Hartshorne, for example.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2470645